# Is there any way to search for a particular registry key on Windows ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get the environment variable details of a particular user(non-administrator) from Administrator and when I was searching manually on `registry editor` found that its located under `Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-..........\Environment`. So came to the conclusion that I have to look for `\HKEY_USERS\*\Environment` and iterate each key to get the desired key and value. When I did google found that I have to pass the path for `Win32::Registry::HKEY_USERS.open()` and not suer how to pass the wildcard kind of value in the path. Any suggestion to get around this or if there is a better way (like getting the list of environment variables for the given username) to get the desired data that also would be great.

Comment: Why not iterate and apply a pattern with `grep`?

Comment: @tadman Thats what I had planned but the path which I have to look is immediate next of the `Win32::Registry::HKEY_USERS`, so not sure what path I have to mentioned in `open()`